# Is there a way to batch rename files involving rearraging the filename based on capitalization

Tags: windows-7, file-management, rename, batch-rename

I want to rename a large amount of files in the format:

`Firstname LASTNAME ABC to yyyymmdd.pdf`

where ABC is a random acronym, and yyyymmdd is the date, to:

`LASTNAME Firstname ABC to yyyymmdd.pdf`

It's on a computer that can't have third party software on it, so lovely tools such as the [Bulk Rename Utility](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/45646/bulk-rename-tool-is-a-lightweight-but-powerful-renaming-tool/) are out of the question. I'm thinking making a batch file to do so, but don't really know where to begin. I've found a bunch of other questions on here and other sites detailing simply how to change case, but I don't want that. The closest I've come is knowing I'll have to use FINDSTR, but I don't have enough experience with command line scripting to proceed any further.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured it out. Pieced together a working batch file from about ten other examples here and on other places:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /F "delims=" %%f in ('dir /A-D /B *.pdf') do (
   for /F "tokens=1-5 delims= " %%a in ("%%~Nf") do (
      ECHO ren "%%f" "%%b %%a %%c %%d %%e!%%~Xf"
      ren "%%f" "%%b %%a %%c %%d %%e!%%~Xf"
   )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your answer can be simplified considerably:-

```
for /F "tokens=1-2*" %%f in ('dir /A-D /B *.pdf') do (
    ECHO ren "%%f %%g %%h" "%%g %%f %%h"
    ren "%%f %%g %%h" "%%g %%f %%h"
)
```

This works because:-

- `"tokens=1-2*"` splits the file name on spaces, with `Firstname` in `%%f`, `LASTNAME` in `%%g` and all the rest of the file name in `%%h`;
- there are no embedded loops, so delayed expansion is not needed (the loop variables are implicitly delayed); and
- there is no directory in the `dir` command, so no special directory handling is needed in the variable expansion.

If the script needs to work with a passed directory name, then surround the above with `pushd %1` and `popd`.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. 

Sometimes there would be more than five tokens (middle name, extra crap) that would get messed up. My workaround was to make more tokens but when they were empty they'd result in trailing whitespace in the filename which was annoying.

Comment: @lolsail - I think my answer covers this, as it splits the name into three tokens, Firstname, LASTNAME and the rest. If you're saying that there could be a middle name or initials between the first and last names, then the problem becomes a lot more complex, and you would probably need to use regular expression processing.

Comment: The middle intials are rare enough that I can fix the few that exist manually. Now I'm just trying to get it to play nice when looping through subdirectories (It takes the directory as the first token and ends up something like:

LASTNAME Dir\Firstname

which of course returns a syntax error)

Comment: okay, figured out how to use the variable modifiers properly, this was my solution:

`ren "%%~dpf%%~nf %%g %%h" "%%g %%~nf %%h"`

Comment: I was thinking about your previous comment when your solution popped up. Well done on finding that!